# How do I draw a polygon with dark borders but transparent facecolors?

Tags: python, matplotlib

In matplotlib I have:

```
cmap = plt.cm.RdYlBu_r
colors = cmap(np.linspace(0,1, len(patches)))
collection = PatchCollection(patches, alpha=.3, 
                             facecolor=colors, linestyle='solid')
```

and it gives me what I want except that the border inherits the "alpha" attribute. How do I draw a polygon with dark borders but transparent facecolors?

Answer (score 2):

as a by-pass solution you could keep the points composing your polygon and plot the line joining the points as in the code below:

```
import matplotlib
import numpy,matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.patches import Polygon
from matplotlib.collections import PatchCollection
fig = plt.figure()
axe = fig.add_subplot(111)
polyval = numpy.random.rand(4,2) # Create the sequence of 4 2D points
patches = [Polygon(polyval,True)]
p = PatchCollection(patches,cmap=matplotlib.cm.jet,alpha=0.3)
p.set_array(100.*numpy.random.rand(1)) # Set a random color on jet map
axe.add_collection(p) 
fig.colorbar(p)
fig.show()
for patch in patches:
   axe.add_patch(Polygon(patch.get_xy(),closed=True,ec='k',lw=3,fill=False)) #draw the contours
fig.canvas.draw()
```